# Passing React State in regular javascript (Helmet)

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I'm trying to pass some data from React to Javascript. How would I pass them to the window object or access the React states from the window? Our analytics code (non-React) needs to have access to some of the data within React.

```
<Helmet>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
     var userId = 'user_123456789'  // This works
     var userId = {userId} // This doesn't work
    </script>
 <script src={withPrefix('analytics')} type="text/javascript" />
</Helmet>
```

Error

```
TypeError: tag[primaryAttributeKey].toLowerCase is not a function
(anonymous function)
node_modules/react-helmet/es/Helmet.js:253
  250 |     return false;
  251 | }
  252 | 
> 253 | var value = tag[primaryAttributeKey].toLowerCase();
  254 | 
  255 | if (!approvedSeenTags[primaryAttributeKey]) {
  256 |     approvedSeenTags[primaryAttributeKey] = {};
```

Comment: `window.userId = { userId }` ?

Comment: @azium - It seems that it's saving { userId } directly so it doesn't have access to the React variable { userId }. Hence, it's saving `var userId = {userId}`  rather than `var userId =  user_a3434`.

Comment: sorry it's hard to tell from your code what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: you do it via `window.yourVar = someThingFromReact`

Comment: oh I see your issue you're trying to use a <script> tag. you can add something to window directly in your react component code

Comment: @azum. Thanks and that worked inside of the render. It should be noted that setting window.yourVar = someThingFromReact didn't work in React Helmet.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting the answer to this, I did this:

```
const Element = () => {
    return (
        <Helmet>
            <script>
                lol = window.url
            </script>`
        </Helmet>
    )
}

useEffect(() => {
    window.url = 'https://what.com';
}, [])
```